# What are the differences among ISIS, Al-Qaeda and the Taliban from an Islamic Perspective?

Tags: sunni, islamic-philosophy, extremism

I've asked a similar question over on a different board however I would like to know what the difference is between these three groups from an Islamic point of view as I believe it would help me gain a better understanding as to why these groups do what they do besides what is heard on the news and other media.

Comment: Please use the relavant tags for the question. The tag "shiism" is not needed I suppose. Please read: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

ISIS is jihadi salafi.they have an idea that it is fard ayn for every muslim to engage in offesnive jihad.this view is rejected by ibn uthaymeen.

alqaeda are just sunni I think.

the Taliban are deobandis and believe in implementation of deobandi Fiqh.

Comment: Just a small correction, Taliban are not all deobandis just a tiny minority of them. They have very similar beliefs as of Barelvis but just don't know about Imam Ahmad Raza (one of the leaders of Barelvis). They have the belief of sufis and do believe on tareqah, tasawwuf, etc. Many of them call themselves from the Naqshbandi Mujaddidi tareeqah of Sufism. While deobandis don't believe on tasawwuf, tareqah, etc. at all. The Taliban have less sect regulations they except all sects except for Shias and strict salafis.